# Cannot use realm with react native and expo in web

Tags: react-native, expo, realm

I'm trying to use realm in react-native web (by running `npm run start` and then pressing `w`), but I'm getting the following error:

```
Web Bundling failed 4940ms
The package at "node_modules\realm\dist\bundle.node.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "node:fs".
It failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library.
```

According to the documentation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/install/#std-label-react-native-install realm is compatible with react-native.

I already installed `@real/react` and it didn't help.
I'm using expo.
Any ideas?